# Missing features in Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api, google-email-settings-api

Please confirm the deprecation date for Email setting API. And please provides the roadmap on this. As we will run into problems if we lose this support.

Bellow is the missing features -

1. Managing language settings
2. Managing delegation settings
3. Managing general settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work on Gmail and the Gmail API platform.*

### Managing Delegation Settings

**We're happy to announce that we have now released the new [Gmail API delegate settings methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings), effectively replacing the long since [deprecated Email Settings API delegation settings methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_delegation_settings).**

You can now use the standard libraries and tools found at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api to interact with the new Gmail delegate settings methods.

We will be publishing a blog post at https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com raising the visibility of the new delegate settings methods in the coming weeks, but I wanted to personally give you a courtesy heads-up.

#### Documentation

- Overview/introduction guide:
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings
- Reference documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates
- Migration guide (from the deprecated [Email Settings API delegation
  methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_delegation_settings)):
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_delegation_settings

### Managing Language and General Settings

As for your concerns regarding the deprecated Email Settings API language settings and general settings methods, [DaImTo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51948949/7955342) is correct:

> These items are not currently available nor is there any information on when / if they will be.

**UPDATE (April 25, 2019)**:

We have released [Gmail API language settings methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/language_settings), replacing the deprecated Email Settings API language settings feature!

Comment: It looks like it is possible to get the list of email accounts one is delegated to. Wondering if it is possible to do the reverse.
i.e.
UserA is delegated to UserB and UserC;
UserD is delegated to UserB and UserD;

Now, it is possible using the APIs to query for UserA and get UserB & UserC.
I'm looking to reverse query UserB and see UserA and UserD.

Answer (score 0):

as per [Email Settings API (deprecated)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/)

> This API is deprecated and will be turned down in Q4 of 2018. Migrate to the Gmail API as soon as possible to avoid disruptions to your application.

The following shows a different date [November 15, 2017](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175187?hl=en)  it was pushed ahead to allow developers time to make other aragments.

**Not available**

As per [Migrate from email settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings)

- Managing language settings Languages settings are not yet available via the API.
- Managing delegation settings Delegation settings are not yet available via the API.
- Managing general settings General settings are no longer available via the API.

These items are not currently available nor is there any information on when / if they will be.

As these features have not been added you will need to remove them from your application as you can no longer use them.

Comment: Thanks, @Dalm for the reply! But this is business application and we cannot remove features from the application. Please provide other alternatives for this.

Comment: There is no alternative.   Even your business application is limited by what features Google decides to allow third party developers to use.    They are not going to work anymore and you will need to remove them or have broken features.